# Unable to use goroutines concurrently to find max until context is cancelled

Tags: go, goroutine

I have successfully made a synchronous solution without goroutines to `findMax` of `compute` calls.

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

func findMax(ctx context.Context, concurrency int) uint64 {
    var (
        max uint64 = 0
        num uint64 = 0
    )

    for i := 0; i < concurrency; i++ {
        num = compute()

        if num > max {
            max = num
        }
    }

    return max
}

func compute() uint64 {
    // NOTE: This is a MOCK implementation of the blocking operation.
    
    time.Sleep(time.Duration(rand.Int63n(100)) * time.Millisecond)
    return rand.Uint64()
}

func main() {
    maxDuration := 2 * time.Second
    concurrency := 10

    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), maxDuration)
    defer cancel()

    max := findMax(ctx, concurrency)
    fmt.Println(max)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/lYXRNTDtNCI

When I attempt to use goroutines to use `findMax` to repeatedly call `compute` function using as many goroutines until context `ctx` is canceled by the caller `main` function. I am getting 0 every time and not the expected max of the grouting compute function calls. I have tried different ways to do it and get deadlock most of the time.

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

func findMax(ctx context.Context, concurrency int) uint64 {
    var (
        max uint64 = 0
        num uint64 = 0
    )

    for i := 0; i < concurrency; i++ {
        select {
        case <- ctx.Done():
            return max
        default:
            go func() {
                num = compute()
                if num > max {
                    max = num
                }
            }()
        }
    }

    return max
}

func compute() uint64 {
    // NOTE: This is a MOCK implementation of the blocking operation.
    
    time.Sleep(time.Duration(rand.Int63n(100)) * time.Millisecond)
    return rand.Uint64()
}

func main() {
    maxDuration := 2 * time.Second
    concurrency := 10

    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), maxDuration)
    defer cancel()

    max := findMax(ctx, concurrency)
    fmt.Println(max)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/3fFFq2xlXAE

Comment: Your program has some incorrect logic as well as data race. See @shmsr's (my) solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your program has multiple problems:

1. You are spawning multiple goroutines that are operating on shared variables i.e., `max` and `num` leading to data race as they are not protected (eg. by Mutex).
2. Here `num` is modified by every worker goroutine but it should have been local to the worker otherwise the computed data could be lost (eg. one worker goroutine computed a result and stored it in num, but right after that a second worker computes and replaces the value of num).

```
 num = compute // Should be "num := compute"
```

3. You are not waiting for every goroutine to finish it's computation and it may result in incorrect results as every workers computation wasn't taken into account even though context wasn't cancelled. Use `sync.WaitGroup` or channels to fix this.

Here's a sample program that addresses most of the issues in your code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

type result struct {
    sync.RWMutex
    max uint64
}

func findMax(ctx context.Context, workers int) uint64 {
    var (
        res = result{}
        wg  = sync.WaitGroup{}
    )

    for i := 0; i < workers; i++ {
        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
            // RLock to read res.max
            res.RLock()
            ret := res.max
            res.RUnlock()
            return ret
        default:
            wg.Add(1)
            go func() {
                defer wg.Done()
                num := compute()

                // Lock so that read from res.max and write
                // to res.max is safe. Else, data race could
                // occur.
                res.Lock()
                if num > res.max {
                    res.max = num
                }
                res.Unlock()
            }()
        }
    }

    // Wait for all the goroutine to finish work i.e., all
    // workers are done computing and updating the max.
    wg.Wait()

    return res.max
}

func compute() uint64 {
    rnd := rand.Int63n(100)
    time.Sleep(time.Duration(rnd) * time.Millisecond)
    return rand.Uint64()
}

func main() {
    maxDuration := 2 * time.Second
    concurrency := 10

    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), maxDuration)
    defer cancel()

    fmt.Println(findMax(ctx, concurrency))
}
```

As @Brits pointed out in the comments that when context is cancelled make sure that you stop those worker goroutines to stop processing (if possible) because it is not needed anymore.

Comment: `return ret` should be `return ret.max`.

Comment: No. I firstly safely read the `res.max` into `ret` and then returned `ret`.

Comment: but you cannot return `ret` if the return type is `uint64`. It must return `ret.max`.

Comment: Note that there is a further issue in that `ctx.Done()` is only checked while starting up the go routines (its more likely that you would want to be able to terminate the computations themselves - i.e. `compute()`).

Comment: @EminLaletovic I didn't do `ret := res` that I have to return `ret.max`. I did `ret := res.max` and `ret` is `uint64`. You can run it locally if you want.

Comment: @Brits Yes, right. It's a good thing that you explicitly pointed it out. But as `compute` is a mock function I didn't do anything to abort those running computations even after the context is canceled. I'd request the OP to handle that on their own.

Comment: @shmsr now I see it, sorry, my bad.

Comment: Code without explanation isn't an answer; the goal of an SO answer should be to teach someone to fish, not give them a fish. Especially for future people having a similar issue who find this question through search.

Comment: @Adrian Okay, I'll keep this in mind. I usually add comments on the relevant parts of the code. No worries, I'll add it. Thanks!

Comment: @Adrian Explained a bit in the description and comments are already there.

Comment: @shmsr Using the channels approach, I would need to create a channel for every worker?